# Origin of Nanka

Tags: hiragana

When watching anime I heard this word come across (Tsuki ga kirei, ep4, somewhere at the end) and I was wondering if it is a combination of nani and ka or just another word. If it is a combination then why would it be used like that? with both nani and ka, which both imply a question.
Alternatively, I know a word exists, which is nanika (I believe it ment: 'something'). Could it be just this word, but then the i removed. If that is the case why would it be removed?
Anyway, it would be appreciated if anyone could shed some more light on this whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なんか is an informal version of 何か (なにか).  So you are correct in your assumption that it is a combination of なに and か.

Interrogative words like なに (what), どこ (where), どれ (which), etc, are known as 'indeterminate pronouns' (see a related answer [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78025/%E3%81%AB-%E3%81%B8-%E3%81%8C-%E3%81%8B-in-describing-place/78026#78026)), and when combined with the particle か, indicate that the object is unidentified. It generally corresponds to 'some ～' in English. Here are some more examples of か being added to indeterminate pronouns:

> なにか something
> だれか somebody
> どこか somewhere
> どちらか one of the two
> いつか some day
> いくつか a few
> いくらか some amount